# Unable to change the configuration from jest to karma ngentest

Tags: jestjs, karma-jasmine, ngentest

I am trying to auto generate unit test code for angular 8 using ngentest library. But when i tried to change the default configuration from jest to karma, even when i changed in ngentest.config.js file of the ngentest module or i copy pasted ngentest.config.js file to root folder of angular or even to the same folder of component where i am trying to generate test case.

```
framework: 'karma', // or 'jest'
```

In all cases, when i tried to generate code, it generates in same jest test case. Any would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For a fix, since I installed `ngentest` as global (`npm install - g ngentest`). I edited global `ngentest` module, configuration file—`ngentest.config.js`. Then, I uncommented the following line:

```
framework: 'karma', // or 'jest'
```

For finding global npm modules, just press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> button and type `%APPDATA%` and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Above is the location where you can find the `\npm\node_modules` folder. This is where global modules sit in your system.

Answer (score 1):

Below commands worked for me :

```
ngentest app-header.component.ts --framework='jest'
ngentest app-header.component.ts --framework='karma'
```

We need to pass the **framework** value as a command line argument

Note: `app-header.component.ts` is the complete path of the component